# Echo **Echo 3> args.txt** >X.bat, how do i fix this code?

Tags: batch-file

Echo **Echo 3> args.txt** >X.bat

I'm trying to place this line of code ( Echo 3> args.txt ) into a batch file named X, but what ends up happening

: X Batch File
echo

:Args text file
There is nothing inside

It place echo (Just echo) into x.batch and creates a blank args text file.
How do I fix the code so it will place **Echo 3> args.txt** into x batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Echo Echo 3^> args.txt>X.bat
```

As `>` has a special meaning (redirect), it must be escaped with `^` to be interpreted as literal character.

One more hint:

Insert no space before `>X.bat` or this space would be appended to end of line in the created batch file.

**cmd.exe** executes this line as

```
Echo Echo 3> args.txt 1>X.bat
```

See also Microsoft's TechNet article [Using command redirection operators](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

---

**EDIT:**

If environment variable **password** could contain also special characters as listed at end of help output in a command prompt window after running `cmd.exe /?`, it would be even better to use:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "password=<hello>"
echo echo var1=!password!^>args.txt>>Enter_PassCode.bat
endlocal
```

The delayed environment variable expansion is explained in help of command **set** output by running `set /?` or `help set`. Delayed expansion is used here to avoid a syntax error on running this batch file because of `<` and `>` in string of environment variable **password**.

This example would append to *Enter_PassCode.bat* the line

```
echo var1=<hello>>args.txt
```

Executing this batch file would of course result again in an error on execution for `<hello>` as password.

A solution for making *Enter_PassCode.bat* executable without any error would be:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "password=<hello>"
echo @echo off>Enter_PassCode.bat
echo setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion>>Enter_PassCode.bat
echo set "password=!password!">>Enter_PassCode.bat
endlocal
echo echo var1=!password!^>args.txt>>Enter_PassCode.bat
echo endlocal>>Enter_PassCode.bat
```

This batch code produces *Enter_PassCode.bat* with content

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "password=<hello>"
echo var1=!password!>args.txt
endlocal
```

Comment: My command line is  "Echo echo var1=%password%^ >args.txt>> Enter_PassCode.bat". when i run it, it outputs "echo var1= " How do you fix that?

Comment: You should edit your question to the real line you have and the expected output in your file

Comment: A trick to keep code readable while avoiding echoing extra spaces is to put the redirect at the beginning of the line.  `>X.bat echo ^>args.txt echo 3`.  This also avoids problems when trying to echo a literal `1` or `2`.  If you try to `echo 2>txtfile`, batch thinks `2` means stderr, rather than a literal numeral 2.